# interview subject on tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

So I was preparing for an interview and came across this question on mirroring binary tree ie to mirror a right subtree to that of left subtree by modifying the existing right subtree

So for a given tree as below

```
                 5                              5
                / \         mirror to        /    \
               7   8      ----------->      7      7
              / \                          / \    / \ 
             3   6                        3   6  6   3
```

Here is what I think, I am not sure though. Correct me if I am wrong

- The key would be the type of traversal?
- I want to traverse the left subtree first, fetch all its data
- Inorder traversal would give me 3, 7, 6, 5, 8.
- Now I want to add new nodes to the right subtree mirroring the data before root 5 ie 3,7 and 6 and copy them to the right subtree. How could we achieve this?

Any help here with pseudo code? thanks!

Comment: It might be easier to think of how to horizontally flip a binary tree.  Once you can do that, you just need to delete the subtree beginning at the root's right child, and replace it with a horizontally-flipped copy of the subtree beginning at the root's left child.

Comment: To think about how to horizontally flip a tree: Obviously, you will need to swap its left and right child subtrees.  Do you need to do anything further to those subtrees?

Comment: Nope I just want to modify and mirror the right subtree to that of left. Hmm let me think on what you suggested.

Comment: I am not sure if the solution you suggested works. If as you said I flip the tree then in my above example subtree with starting node 8 would move to the left and subtree with starting node 7 would move  to the right. Now if i delete roots right child it will delete the subtree starting with 7 which is what I want to mirror and not delete. Am I missing out on something? Would you please clarify the same? thanks

Comment: My first comment was suggesting a way that you can achieve what you want by breaking the task into (slightly) simpler subproblems.  My second comment was describing (in part) how to achieve the flipping I talked about in my first comment, not the entire goal.